# Make $\sin(x)-x\cos(x)$ beautiful?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-series, trigonometric-integrals

When computing a Fourier series I came across a term like $$\sin(x)-x\cos(x)$$ Is there a way to reduce this expression, e.g. to only $sin$ or $cos$?

My final series looks like this:
$$ f(t) = \dfrac{4U}{T^2\omega^2n^2} \sum^\infty_{n=1} \left( \sin(n\omega T/2) - n\omega T/2 \cdot \cos(n\omega T/2) \right) \sin(n\omega t) $$

Comment: No, but integration by parts should aid any problem you have.

Comment: @Wojowu This was the results after integration by parts.

Comment: If you just want to "tidy up" the term, nothing can be done.

Comment: Note that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin x-x\cos x=x\sin x$

Answer (score 0):

You can write

$$\sin(x)-x\cos(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sin(x)-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cos(x)\right)$$

So:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ \exists\theta_x\in[-\pi,\pi],\ \cos(\theta_x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}},\ \sin(\theta_x)=-\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$

Just useful in terms of esthetic.

Answer (score 0):

This may be acceptable. Let $\, z := x - \tan^{-1}(x). \,$ Then
 $\, \sin(x) - x \cos(x) = \sin(z) / \cos(x-z) $ which is a quotient of $\,\sin\,$ and $\,\cos.$